# Cannot use a json object, unexpected token (comma)

Tags: java, gson

I parse an arraylist using GSON, and this gave me

```
[["1","user","test"],["2","another","test",["3","last one","test"]]
```

And I cannot JSON parse it so that I can loop through it like

```
for(i < 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
   console.log("some sentence" + obj[i][0] + " etc etc")
}
```

it keeps me giving the total length of the characters of that array.

Comment: Sorry but I didn't fully get the question, if you are using `Gson` to serialize the `ArrayList` why don't you use `Gson` to deserialize it?

Answer (score 1):

The JSON Structure is malformed. A "]" is missing after second array I think. After correction it will be like this...

```
[
  [
    "1", 
    "user", 
    "test"
  ], 
  [
    "2", 
    "another", 
    "test"
  ], 
  [
    "3", 
    "last one", 
    "test"
  ]
]
```

Edit :

Probably your parsing method is not correct. Your String is JSONArray in which there are another 3 JSONArrays. So, Parsing should be like this

```
String str = "your json string above" ;

try {
    JSONArray array = new JSONArray(str);
    for(int i = 0 ; i < array.length() ; i++){
    JSONArray nestedArray = array.getJSONArray(i);
        for(int j = 0 ; j < nestedArray.length() ; j++){
        System.out.println("" + nestedArray.getString(j) + "\n");
        }
    }       
} catch (JSONException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To parse your JSON string (correct it adding missing `]`) you can do something like this:

```
String json = "[[\"1\",\"user\",\"test\"],[\"2\",\"another\",\"test\"],[\"3\",\"f**er\",\"test\"]]";

Type listType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>>>(){}.getType();
ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>> list = new Gson().fromJson(json, listType);
for(List innerList : list)
   for(Object o : innerList){
        System.out.println(o);
```

This will give you a simple data structure that will easily fit to your needs.